# conflicts related to multiple declaration of JQuery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

The website I am working on got javascript bugs I am trying to solve.

On the same page , on top of other scripts, I got multiple declaration as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.touch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/QapTcha.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slides.min.jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js" ></script>
```

Is there some declarations I can safely remove ?

How can I make sure anyhow that these scripts are coexisting without conflict?

Comment: I'd remove one of the first two - you don't really want two different versions of jQuery on the same page, they will conflict. I couldn't tell you whether any of the plugins conflict with each other, or whether the different plugins actually expect different versions of jQuery.

Comment: +1 for @nnnnnn. Only one of the first two can be safely removed.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.4.2.js">
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   var jq_4 = jQuery.noConflict();  
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.js">
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   var jq_6 = jQuery.noConflict();  
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.7.js">
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   var jq_7 = jQuery.noConflict();  
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   // You can use different instance of jquery library.   
   jq_4(document).ready(function () {  
     // so now you can use jquery jq variable instead of $ .   
     jq_4("div").hide();  
   });  
   jq_7(document).ready(function () {  
     // so now you can use jquery jq variable instead of $ .   
     jq_7("div").hide();  
   });  
</script>
```